# Issue with JSON conversion

Tags: java, json, jackson

Below is my sample JSON data. Its giving the below exception during conversion. There is another class that has the list of transactions.

Transactions

```
public class Transactions{
      private String id; 
      private ThisAccount thisAccount; 
      private OtherAccount otherAccount; 
      private Details details; 
      private Metadata metadata; 

      public String getId(){
        return id; 
      }
      public void setId(String input){
         this.id = input;
      }
      public ThisAccount getThisAccount(){
        return thisAccount; 
      }
      public void setThisAccount(ThisAccount input){
         this.thisAccount = input;
      }
      public OtherAccount getOtherAccount(){
        return otherAccount; 
      }
      public void setOtherAccount(OtherAccount input){
         this.otherAccount = input;
      }
      public Details getDetails(){
        return details; 
      }
      public void setDetails(Details input){
         this.details = input;
      }
      public Metadata getMetadata(){
        return metadata; 
      }
      public void setMetadata(Metadata input){
         this.metadata = input;
      }
      public String toString() {
          return this.getId();
      }
}
```

JSON

```
{  
   "transactions":[  
      {  
         "id":"dcb8138c-eb88-404a-981d-d4edff1086a6",
         "this_account":{  
            "id":"savings-kids-john",
            "holders":[  
               {  
                  "name":"Savings - Kids John",
                  "is_alias":false
               }
            ],
            "number":"832425-00304050",
            "kind":"savings",
            "IBAN":null,
            "swift_bic":null,
            "bank":{  
               "national_identifier":"rbs",
               "name":"The Royal Bank of Scotland"
            }
         },
         "other_account":{  
            "id":"c83f9a12-171e-4602-9a92-ae895c41b16b",
            "holder":{  
               "name":"ALIAS_CBCDE5",
               "is_alias":true
            },
            "number":"13677980653",
            "kind":"CURRENT PLUS",
            "IBAN":"BA12 1234 5123 4513 6779 8065 377",
            "swift_bic":null,
            "bank":{  
               "national_identifier":null,
               "name":"The Bank of X"
            },
            "metadata":{  
               "public_alias":null,
               "private_alias":null,
               "more_info":null,
               "URL":null,
               "image_URL":null,
               "open_corporates_URL":null,
               "corporate_location":null,
               "physical_location":null
            }
         },
         "details":{  
            "type":"sandbox-payment",
            "description":"Description abc",
            "posted":"2016-10-09T20:01:53Z",
            "completed":"2016-10-09T20:01:53Z",
            "new_balance":{  
               "currency":"GBP",
               "amount":null
            },
            "value":{  
               "currency":"GBP",
               "amount":"10.00"
            }
         },
         "metadata":{  }
      },
      {  
         "id":"06ffa118-7892-45c7-8904-f938766680dd",
         "this_account":{  },
         "other_account":{  },
         "details":{  },
         "metadata":{  }
      },
      {  
         "id":"2d633a56-cd59-4ee5-8dae-142750a1a1b4",
         "this_account":{  },
         "other_account":{  },
         "details":{  },
         "metadata":{  }
      },
]
}
```

Exception

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "this_account" (class com.transactionRetrieval.controller.Transactions), not marked as ignorable (5 known properties: "details", "id", "otherAccount", "thisAccount", "metadata"])
 at [Source: java.io.StringReader@7d8ea76c; line: 1, column: 79] (through reference chain: com.transactionRetrieval.controller.TransactionsList["transactions"]->java.util.ArrayList[0]->com.transactionRetrieval.controller.Transactions["this_account"])
```

Does it have to do anything with the variable name being thisAccount instead of this_account. Is there a way to map this. Is there way to make work?

Answer (score 4):

> Does it have to do anything with the variable name being thisAccount instead of this_account.

Yes, it does.

> Is there a way to map this.

Yes, look for point number 3

> Is there way to make work?

Yes, 3 of them that I can think right now

---

Your JSON contains a field called `this_account`, but your class doesn't, it contains `thisAccount`.

There are 3 ways for solving this:

1. Change your variable name to: `this_account`
2. Change your JSON field to `thisAccount`
3. **(Recommended)** Use the `@JsonProperty` annotation on `thisAccount` like this:

   ```
   @JsonProperty("this_account")
   private ThisAccount thisAccount;
   ```

   This, will "link" or "map" your JSON property `this_account` to the variable `thisAccount`.

You need to do the same thing for all the rest of your variables / fields in your JSON and class that have a different name.

Reference: https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-annotations#annotations-for-renaming-properties

Answer (score 1):

Even though is other answer to your question works, I do not think that annotating every single property will be the recommended way to do it. Instead, use a naming strategy:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);
```

Answer (score 1):

Frakcool's recommendation allows you to be explicit when linking the JSON property name to the Java property name, which is often the safest way to go.

But there may be something simpler for your example: it looks like the naming follows a pattern, in which `multi_word_property` in JSON becomes `multiWordProperty` in Java.

That's a common enough style that Jackson actually has built-in support for it. When you're creating your `ObjectMapper`, you can configure it like so:

```java
ObjectMapper mapper = ...;

// jackson-databind versions ≥ 2.7
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(PropertyNamingStrategy.SNAKE_CASE);

// jackson-databind versions < 2.7
mapper.setPropertyNamingStrategy(
  PropertyNamingStrategy.CAMEL_CASE_TO_LOWER_CASE_WITH_UNDERSCORES);
```

The mapper should handle the structure from your example after that.